# Unequal bond lengths of resonating bonds in dinitrogen trioxide

Tags: bond, resonance

Here is an image showing the resonance structures of $\ce{N2O3}$ molecule,[image]

As the bonds numbered **(2)** and **(3)** are in resonance, they will have same bond lengths but each with bond order less than two. As the bond numbered **(1)** doesn't involve in resonance, it will have a bond order of two. Hence, the order of $\ce{N-O}$ bond lengths is **(1)>(2)=(3)**.

But according to [Wikipedia,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_trioxide) all the three $\ce{N-O}$ bond lengths are of different lengths! Here is an image form Wikipedia showing the bond lengths and the bond angles in $\ce{N2O3}$,[image]
So my question is why are the resonating bonds are of different lengths?

Comment: Bonds don't "resonate", and in dissymmetric molecule won't be equal

Comment: Consider the relative energies of the two resonance structures

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by and why you think "As the bonds numbered (2) and (3) are in resonance, they will have same bond lengths"?

Comment: @Mithoron if the bonds aren't in resonance, then there could be a significant difference in the bond lengths of bonds **(2)** and **(3)**.

Comment: @Andrew I understand what you are saying. So according to bond lengths data, second resonating structure is more contributing than the first one. Can you explain, why?

Comment: The experiment describes what actually happens, not a theoretical resonance structure :)  So we must assume that there is limited rotation about the N-N bond otherwise the two bonds in the NO2 part would have the same length and same angles  by symmetry.  (Perhaps some rotation is happening as lengths are v similar and perhaps if the experiment was done at a lower temperature there might be a bigger difference in bond lengths and angles? )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two oxygen atoms on the $\ce{NO2}$ nitrogen are not equivalent. The molecule is planar*, and one $\ce{NO2}$ oxygen (call it the "cis" oxygen) is closer to the third oxygen atom than the other $\ce{NO2}$ oxygen ("trans").

We then note that the oxygen atoms have nonbonding pairs around them, which tend to repel each other. So the cis oxygen will tend to form a stronger pi bond, pushing more nonbonding electron density onto the relatively remote trans oxygen.

*This planarity is due to hyperconjugation. See [Halpern et al[1]](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17461624/).

**Reference**

1. Halpern AM, Glendening ED (2007 Apr 21). "Ab initio study of the torsional potential energy surfaces of N2O3 and N2O4: origin of the torsional barriers." *J Chem Phys.*; **126**(15):154305. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2713756. PMID: 17461624.

Comment: What is the reason the NO group orientation is locked? Does  the N-N bond have partially pi-character too? As it does not seem that there is a sterical obstacle for the bond to rotate.

Comment: [Halpern et al](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17461624/): "N(2)O(4) and N(2)O(3) exhibit strong hyperconjugative interactions of in-plane O lone pairs with the central N-N sigma* antibond. Hyperconjugative stabilization is somewhat stronger at the planar geometries because 1,4 interactions of lone pairs on cis O atoms promote delocalization of electrons into the N-N antibond. "